# How to get a HDD running status led monitor in the taskbar

Tags: hard-drive, taskbar

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10.

I want to know if there is a way to get a HHD running status (as a led monitor light) into the standard taskbar of the screen.

It is intended because my Laptop PC has this light at the right side panel,  full invisible to the user. Don't ask me why the design engineer did it this way.

Is there a way to get this? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can!

The [System Load Indicator](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/display-cpu-memory-network-usage-in-ubuntu-18-04-panel/) is in the Universe repository and can be added to your system easily, then configured [following these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/display-cpu-memory-network-usage-in-ubuntu-18-04-panel/) to give you a blinkenlight for your drive. Start by running this in a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0  gir1.2-clutter-1.0`

Then, open Ubuntu Software. Look for ‘system monitor extension’ and install it.

Once installed, click on it to show its drop-down menu, then pick Preferences and change the applet appearance to give you the LED-like look for drive activity.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Install `Harddisk LED` GNOME extension. It can be found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/988/harddisk-led/

---

[image]

---